# Azure Storage Explorer: Properties of type '' are not supported error

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I inherited a project that uses an Azure table storage database.  I'm using Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer as a tool to query and manage data.  I'm attempting to migrate data from my Dev database to my QA database.  To do this, I'm exporting a CSV from a Dev database table and then trying to import into the QA database table.  For a small number of tables, I get the following error when I try to import the CSV:

> Failed: Properties of type '' are not supported.

When I ran into this before, since I exported a "typed" CSV from Dev, I checked to make sure all "@type" columns had values.  They did.  Then I split the CSV (with thousands of records) up into smaller files to try to determine which record was the issue.  When I did this and started importing them, I was ultimately able to import all of the records successfully by individual files which is peculiar.  Almost like a constraint violation issue.

I'm also seeing errors with different types.  Eg:

> Properties of type 'Double' are not supported.

In this case, there is already a column in the particular table of type "Double".

Anyway, now that I'm seeing it again, I'm having trouble resolving it.  Any thoughts?

**UPDATE**
I was able to track a few of these errors to "bad" data in the CSV.  It was a JSON string in a `Edm.String` field that for some reason, it wasn't liking.  I minified the JSON using an online tool and it imported fine. There is one data set, though, that has over 7,000 records I'm trying to import (the one I referenced breaking up previously earlier in this post).  I ended up breaking it up into different files and was able to successfully import them individually.  When I try to import the entire file after loading all the data through individual files, though, I again get an error.

Answer (score 1):

> I split the CSV (with thousands of records) up into smaller files to try to determine which record was the issue. When I did this and started importing them, I was ultimately able to import all of the records successfully by individual files which is peculiar.

Based on your test, the format and data of source CSV file seems ok. It will be difficult to find out why Azure Storage Explorer return those unexpected error while importing large CSV file. You can try to upgrade your Azure Storage Explorer and check if you can export and import data successfully using the latest Azure Storage Explorer.

Besides, you can try to use AzCopy *(designed for copying data to and from Microsoft Azure Blob, File, and Table storage using simple commands with optimal performance)* to [export/import table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#table-import).

**Export table:**

```
AzCopy /Source:https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/myTable/ /Dest:C:\myfolder\ /SourceKey:key /Manifest:abc.manifest
```

**Import table:**

```
AzCopy /Source:C:\myfolder\ /Dest:https://myaccount.table.core.windows.net/mytable1/ /DestKey:key /Manifest:"abc.manifest" /EntityOperation:InsertOrReplace
```

Comment: Can you apply filters to the AzCopy command?  Also, I updated my post.

Comment: I did a little more digging.  You cannot apply filters at this time.  The alternative is to manually export the data from tables into a CSV and then use the import command, but unfortunately AzCopy imports only works with JSON (manifests) not CSVs (manually export).  What an application...

Comment: Yes, importing table entities from CSV format payload is not supported currently.